# Dialogflow CX Custom Payloads

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-cx

I am trying DialogFlow CX custom payload but the response is just {custom payload}
[image]

Here is the JSON I use:

```
{
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "text": [
          "This is text line 1.",
          "This is text line 2."
        ],
        "type": "description",
        "title": "Description title"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I expect there is atleast the custom payload UI shown on the Test Agent page.

Comment: Can you follow this [Document](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment#payload) it is related to customer payload. I hope it will help you ?

Comment: I have tried that and other custom payloads templates from select templates. But it didn't work. https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment#custom-payload-templates

Comment: Does this [link](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger) help you for the custom payload UI shown on the Test Agent page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will always see that from the testing tool, just for debugging purposes. To see that in action, you will need to test it with the integration itself!

Answer (score 0):

Manage > Integrations > Text Based > Dialogflow Messenger

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So it can only show custom payload through DialogFlow Messenger?

Comment: yes, that is correct! If you want to test how it looks like, you will need to test it in the integration itself, not in the simulator!

Answer (score 0):

that is correct Viz! I created a typescript example about Dialogflow CX and that integration: https://github.com/xavidop/dialogflow-cx-webhook-pokedex

Comment: would be nice of you to expand. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587. what are you even saying is correct?